# If a 110 volt motor asks for 4W does that mean I will have to change the wall power?

Tags: motor, watts

[image: Here is the spec sheet for this motor]

I am new to electronics like motors so help on how to set this up would be awesome.

Comment: Yes if you're in 230V land.

Answer (score 3):

If you have 110V 60Hz you just connect it to the mains (perhaps with a fuse in series) and it will draw the power it needs (4W), and will turn at 10 RPM (the 8.3 RPM figure in the datasheet is for 50Hz power).

---

If you **don't** have 110V 60Hz but have 200V 60Hz or 230V 50Hz or 120V 400Hz or 28VDC or 12VDC etc. then you need to convert. If the frequency is what you want but the voltage is wrong, a small transformer is probably easiest. Otherwise more complex solutions are called for. For example, an inverter or a 400Hz motor driving a 60Hz generator.

Comment: If my wall power is 120v is it insignificant enough of a difference for it to be safely ignored?

Comment: Probably, I would guess, but there's not really enough information to be sure, even on the manufacturer's website. Don't run it in a hot location.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but what is a "hot location".

Answer (score 0):

4 watts at 110 volts is 0.0364 amps. If your wall voltage is 110 volts, it will probably supply at least 10 amps before the circuit breaker blows. That enough power to run 275 of those motors. In other words, 4 watts is a trivial amount of power to pull from a typical 110 volt wall socket.